# React Native: Flexbox order property

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Trying to use the `order` property of flexbox on React Native, but got an error `"order is not a valid style property"`.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ...
  myFlexItem: {
    order: 2
  },
});
```

The docs for CSS order are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order, is there anything similar on React Native?

Comment: Provide us with a code sample that reproduce the error, and if you are looking for RN docs, you are at the wrong place

Comment: Added code. Not looking for RN docs, as written in my question, looking for something "similar on React Native".

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297640/react-nativeorder-is-not-a-valid-style-property ... so I guess you need to add it using CSS styles instead.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox is not applicable in React Native. RN's flexbox only supports basic properties *flexDirection*, *alignItems*, *justifyContent*, and the *flex* attributes. You can refer to this document link given -
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox